# Bootstrap 5: Table in a second column jumps below the first column

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table, bootstrap-5

I have a grid layout with some navigation pills in the left column set to "col-auto" because I want these to only take up the space of the content's natural width.

In the second table I want to have a large table with horizontal scrollbar. I'm able to achieve this except the table always jumps below the navigation bar and I can't get it to be rendered to the right.

See in the attached fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3vxhd6jf/3/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-auto"> <!-- Should only take up the necessary space -->
       <!-- Nav tabs -->
       <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
       .....
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col"> <!-- Should take up the rest of the space -->
       <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-data" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-data">
           <div id="div-data-container" class="mb-3 table-responsive">
             <!-- The table -->
             <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
             .....
             </table>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve is to render the table to the right of the navigation pills, just like the textarea is rendered when you click the 'JSON' pill.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows in Bootstrap are flex containers that allow wrapping by default. If you want to force your columns onto the same line, you need to prevent that wrapping.

Apply the `flex-nowrap` class to your row:

```
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
```

With everything on one row, you'll find the size of the table causes it to overflow. You're already utilising Bootstrap's `table-responsive` class. Put `overflow-hidden` on the column containing the table to keep the content within the row.

```
<div class="col overflow-hidden"> <!-- tab content / table markup / etc -->
```

Further reading: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#wrap

Comment: This keeps the table to the right of the navigation pills, but it also doesn't shrink the table and it overflows the page. Should I do something else as well?

Comment: @janhink Ah the fun of tables. Bootstrap is handling the responsive nature of the table with the 'table-responsive' class. Put overflow-hidden on your col containing the table. I'll update the answer to cover that.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I don't even have to use the .flex-nowrap, just the .overflow-hidden does the trick